# How to specify a display name in emails from SSRS subscriptions?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

How can I specify a display name (e.g. "**Reporting Server**" <noreply@domain.com>) in the emails sent from SSRS subscriptions?

Answer (score 1):

This will need to be set up in Exchange Properties for the email address which you specify in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager